# Заполнить клетки прямоугольника 2*100 непрерывной последовательностью чисел

Tags: алгоритм, математика

В тетрадке нарисован прямоугольник 2×100. Требуется записать в его клетки числа от 1 до 200 так, что любые два числа, отличающиеся на единицу были записаны в клетки, соседние по стороне. Сколько существует способов это сделать?

Comment: Задачка, конечно, интересная, но вам нужно решить ее самой.

Comment: Подскажите,хоть с чего начать,пожалуйста?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как **не соответствующего теме**, потому что он относится к математике, а не к программированию.

Comment: гуглите Биномиальный коэффициент, сочетания

Comment: @KromStern, это не математика, а алгоритмы, а они имеют прямое отношение к программированию.

Comment: @Ирина с построения математической модели начать. Судя по формулировке, задача из области комбинаторики.

Comment: Что-то у меня либо голова болит, либо таких перестановок там и правда `100!`

Comment: Если можно повторять числа тогда тогда `200^100` штук(этот прямоугольник просто регистр на `100` числел от `1` до `200`), если нет `100!`(число перестановок для множества из `100` элементов).

Comment: Да откуда вы берете такие большие числа-то?  Не забыли, что соседние числа должны быть написаны рядом?

Comment: @Ирина, а что вы сделали для решения задачи сами? Или вопрос сводится к "_решите за меня_"?

Comment: @Pavel Смотря что значит соседние по стороне? Какой стороне? Столбцу которых 100 штук или строке которых 2 или по столбцу и по строке? Если по стобцу то большое число получается, такие суровые комбинаторные реалии.

Comment: @igumnov, "соседи по стороне" - это общеизвестное понятие. В данной в условиях задачи конструкиции у каждой клетки 3 соседа по стороне (кроме угловых - там два).

Comment: Я не могу понять как должны расставляться числа,у меня не получается,чтобы любые два числа отличались на 1.

Comment: @Ирина, значит пользователи ru.so должны таки решить задачу _за вас_.

Comment: @Ирина, не любые 2 числа отличались, а два соседних числа были соседями. Надо просто заполнить непрерывной последовательностью 1 2 3 4 5 ... 200, по принципу "не отрывая карандаша от бумаги", т. е. каждое следующее число в соседней клетке с предыдущим.

Comment: @Ирина, вам не требуется, чтобы *любые соседние числа отличались на единицу*! От вас требуют обратного: *любые числа, отличающиеся на единицу, должны быть соседями*.

Comment: я просто не понимаю,что такое любые два числа, отличающиеся на единицу были записаны в клетки, соседние по стороне .Буду благодарна,если объясните.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Более того там еще может быть соседство по диагонали.
`13 %перевод_строки% 
 42`.

Comment: @igumnov, нет. Там сказано соседние по стороне.

Comment: @BOPOH: Не согласен. Как именно программист или администратор БД решит этот вопрос и/или использует в своей работе? SO - база вопросов и решений по конкретным проблемам, а не абстрактным алгоритмическим задачкам (типа "Как найти фальшивую монету за 3 взвешивания" или "расположить числа от 1 до 100 в ячейках")

Comment: @KromStern, программист на собеседовании?))

Comment: @Qwertiy: Тогда уж и вопросы типа "Кем вы видите себя через 5 лет" окажутся по теме ;-)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27681/discussion-on-question-by-----2100-).

Answer (score 3):

**Лемма**
Если зафиксировать столбцы, на которых находятся числа 1 и 200, то

- существует ровно 2 варианта решения если столбцы различные,
- существует ровно 2 варианта решения если это один и тот же столбец и он - крайний,
- в остальных случаях решения не существует.

Доказательство очевидно *(т.е. мне лень его писать)*.

**Решение**
Всего 100*100 вариантов выбора столбцов для чисел 1 и 200, из них 98 - невозможные.

Итого - 2*(100*100 - 98) = **19804** варианта.

Где я ошибся? :)

Comment: Первый буллет в лемме неочевиден.

Comment: Отлично и лаконично! Тоже хотел плясать от концов, но отвлёкся.

Comment: Круто!!! И очень красиво.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуем решить задачу рекурсивно.

Пусть F(*n*) — количество решений для доски 2 × *n*, G(*n*) — количество решений для доски 2 × *n*, которые начинаются в левом нижнем углу. (Мы предполагаем, что прямоугольник расположен горизонтально).

Не ограничивая общности, предположим, что первая точка расположена внизу (это уменьшает количество вариантов для F(*n*) вдвое).

Очевидно, в каждом из путей должен быть вертикальный отрезок. Рассмотрим *первый* из них. Пусть он будет на *k*-ом шагу. Наш путь имеет вид

```
            k+1
1  2  3 ...  k
```

У нас есть такие варианты:

1) *k* ≠ 1, и верхняя часть идёт в том же направлении, что и первый отрезок:

```
                k+1 k+2
1  2  3 ... k-1  k
```

В левую часть от *k* + 1 попасть невозможно, и эта часть непуста. Итак, этот вариант невозможен.

2) *k* ≠ 1, и верхняя часть идёт в противоположном от первого отрезка направлении.

```
            k+2 k+1
1  2  3 ... k-1  k
```

при этом наш путь не может попасть в правую часть, то есть, она должна быть пустая. То есть путь выглядит так:

```
2k 2k-1 2k-2 ... k+2 k+1|
 1   2    3  ... k-1  k |
```

Остаток доски имеет размеры 2 × (*n* − *k*), и её можно обойти G(*n* − *k*) способами.

3) *k* = 1

```
2  3
1
```

при этом наш путь не может попасть в левую часть, значит, она должна быть пуста, то есть имеем такую картинку:

```
|2  3
|1
```

Количество вариантов обхода равно G(*n* − 1).

Составим рекуррентные соотношения.

Для произвольной начальной точки: Количество вариантов в 1) равно 0. Количество вариантов в 2) равно сумме по всем возможным `k` (от 2 до *n*) величин G(*n* − *k*), т. е., G(*n* − 2) + G(*n* − 3) + ... + G(*n* − *n*) = G(0) + G(1) + ... + G(*n* − 2). Эту сумму надо ещё умножить на 2, для двух возможных направлений (влево и вправо), и ещё на 2 для двух возможных строк для начальной точки. Количество вариантов для 3) равно G(*n* − 1), и это надо умножить на 2 для двух возможных строк для начальной точки, и ещё на 2 для положения единицы слева и справа. Итого:

G(*n*) = 4 × [G(0) + G(1) + ... + G(*n* − 1)]

Теперь составим рекуррентное соотношение для G(*n*). Рассмотрим те же три варианта (помним, что 1 находится в левом нижем углу).

Вариант 1) невозможен по тем же причинам.

Вариант 2) по сути означает такую картинку

```
|2k 2k-1 2k-2 ... k+2 k+1|
| 1   2    3  ... k-1  k |
```

то есть *k* = *n*, это даёт ровно один вариант при *n* > 1 и ни одного варианта при *n* = 1.

Вариант 3) остаётся неизменным и даёт G(*n* − 1) вариант.

Итого:

G(0) = 1
G(1) = 1
G(*n*) = 1 + G(*n* − 1) для *n* > 1

Отсюда легко выходит, что G(*n*) = *n* при *n* > 0.

Окончательно получаем: F(100) = 4 × ([1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 99]) = 4 + 4 × 99 × 100 / 2 = 19804.

Надеюсь, что нигде не ошибся.

Comment: Почему вы считаете F(200) вместо F(100)? :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Тьфу! И правда.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Окей, ответы сошлись. Теперь объясните вашу комбинаторную модель, она явно проще.

Comment: Написал ниже...

Answer (score 1):

*Лемма 1*. Фрагмент пути может быть только двух видов: *змейка* или *петля*. *Змейка* – непрерывная цепочка вертикальных *П*-образных фрагментов, где чередуется их вертикальная направленность. *Петля* – горизонтальный *П*-образный фрагмент, где ножки могут быть любой (и разной) длины.

*Лемма 2*. Петля хотя бы с одной стороны подходит к краю.

*Лемма 3*. Петель может быть 0, 1 или 2.

*Лемма 4*. Змеек может быть 0 или 1. Наличие Змейки разрывает концы Пути (0 и 200). При отсутствии змейки концы соседствуют.

Минимальной длиной Петли по горизонтали считаем 1 переход (2 значения):

```
1 2
4 3
```

Минимальной длиной Змейки по горизонтали считаем 2 перехода (3 значение по гор.:

```
1 2
  3 4
```

Сосчитаем варианты:

```
Петли  Змейка  Варианты
0      0       0 – нет такого варианта
0      1       4 - из каждого из углов стартует змейка по вертикали
1      0       200 * 2 - все варианты одной петли
1      1       4 * ? - про этот случай дальше.
2      1       4 * ? - про этот случай дальше:
```

Петля и змейка. Минимальная длина такой штуки - 4. 96 остаётся для распределения. Сколькими способами можно составить 96 из двух натуральных слагаемых, считая нули? `0+96, 1+95 .. 95+1, 96+0 = 97` вариантов. Не забыть домножить на 2 (порядок змейки и петли), и на 4, т.к. симметрия. **+776**

В случае, когда есть 2 петли и змейка, минимальная длина такой конструкции 5: `ПZП`. Остаётся 95 позиций для распределения среди трёх элементов. Задача сводится к кол-ву [композиций](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0) 95 из трёх слагаемых, считая нули, и учитывая порядок. Формула для кол-ва композиций числа n из k слагаемых, считая нули:

```
( n + k - 1 )     скобки высотой две строки
(   k - 1   )
```

Пусть верхняя часть `N = n + k - 1`, а нижняя `M = k - 1`. Вычисляется как

```
    N!
-----------
K! * (N-K)!
```

Для 95 и 3 у меня получилось 4656 и домножить на 4. **+18624**

```
Петли  Змейка  Варианты
0      0       0
0      1       4
1      0       400
1      1       776
2      1       18624
--------------------
               19804
```

**Результат: 19804**. А теперь выкладывайте простой, как двоичные числа, тривиальный вариант решения, который наверняка есть. )

**Upd**. глядя на два независимых других результата @pavel-mayorov и @vladd, исправил ошибку у себя – не учитывал сначала порядок змейки-петли в варианте 1:1.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так (не проверял):

1. Поместить единицу в левую верхнюю клетку.
2. Вараинты записи есть либо змейкой, либо, начало змейкой, а потом по прямой до конца и обратно во втором ряду. Думаю, дла этого можно составить формулу.
3. Из соображений симметрии, умнодить ответ на 4.
4. Ещё умножить на 2 и вычесть 4 - это то, что началось со змейки, а кончилось невырожденным кольцом, если идти по нему в обратную сторону.
5. Добавить 2*196 как кольца в двух направлениях с любой клетки, кроме угловых.

Данный ответ некорректен, не учтен варианты такого плана:

```
2 1 6 7  8
3 4 5 10 9
```

Спасибо @PavelMayorov за нахождение этого случая.

6. Добавить 2*96 конструкций приведённого выше вида.

Comment: Единицу нельзя поместить в угол, потому что для нее не существует двух чисел из заданного диапазона, отличающихся ровно на единицу.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, что? Нужно, чтобы любые два числа, отличающиеся на 1 были в соседних клетках. Ничего про 2 соседних числа, во-первых, не говорится, во-вторых, такое размещение было бы невозможно. Все размещения - это циклы с любой клетки и змейки с угла, возможно, заканчивающиеся прямыми кусками с разворотом.

Comment: Вы слишком замудрили все дело. Тут только два столбца. И пар только 100.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, либо в угол, либо с любой клетки кольцом. Других вариантов нет, т. к. как только область распадётся на две свободные части, ты уже не сможешь перейти из одной в другую не разрывая цепь. Вот если бы там было хотя бы 3 клетки в ширину, то было бы больше вариантов. Если не согласен, приведи какой-нибудь пример, где единица не в углу и последовательность не образует кольцо.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я наконец понял, что обозначает это выражение "соседние по стороне" :D

Comment: @PavelMayorov, понятно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, если их ещё добавить, то все?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, все. Но их не 2*96 - потому что "змейка посередине" может быть любой длины. Ответ на эту задачу 19804 - можете теперь подсчитать, сколько "конструкций такого вида" вы пропустили :)

Comment: @Qwertiy - еще не учли 2 1 6 7 10           
3 4 5 8 9

Comment: @Mirdin, здесь 10 в углу - кажется, это один из симметричных вариантов, получаемых за счёт умножения на 4.

Comment: @Qwertiy - еще не учли 2 1 6 7 10 11 12      3 4 5 8 9 14 13

Comment: @Mirdin, хотя нет. Надо тогда там на 8 умножить и 4 вычесть.

Comment: Не хватает доказательства того, что приведённый список случаев — исчерпывающий :-)

Comment: @Qwertiy - смотрите, у нас есть варианты, РАЗНЫЕ : 1. Кольцо полное 2 Змейка из угла 3 Кольцо неполное + произвольное количество клеток змейкой + кольцо неполное. Вот с третьим вариантом как раз и проблемы.

Comment: @VladD, тут явно надо избежать разбиения на 2 области, которое получается любой вертикальной линией. Т. е. каждый раз, проводя вертикальную линию, мы должны быть уверены, что хотя бы с одной стороны от неё всё уже заполнено. При этом, мы уже привязаны к этой линии углом, т. е.  сбоку гарантированно змейка с кольцом (причём, любая или обе части могут быть вырождены до нлевой ширины). Осталось понять, как это посчитать. Похоже на какую-то динамику...

Comment: @Mirdin, см. комментарий выше - там точно всё, но при попытке это подсчитать вкралась охапка упрощений, из-за чего потерялись варианты.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Угу, каждая вертикальная линия делит на две области, которые надо заполнить независимо. Кажется, можно сделать рекурсивно.

Comment: @Qwertiy - там 96 надо умножать не на 2 а на 4, вроде бы, так можно пройтись змейкой, а можно закрутить кольцо

Comment: @VladD, там нет рекурсии, поскольку проводя линию, мы уже фиксируем конечную точку, а при рекурсивном вызове этой фиксации нет. Ещё проблема, что куски змейки содержат много вертикальных линий и, если за основу брать вертикальное разделение, посчитаются в каждой из них - надо как-то этого избежать.

Comment: Вот черт, элементарная формулировка, а дело пахнет перечислительной комбинаторикой. У меня не хватает воображения, чтобы посторить это множество и оценить его мощность. Если кто-нибудь найдет верный ответ, поделитесь ссылкой.

Comment: Приводить решение не буду - но намекну. *2 * (100 * 100 - 98)* Никакой динамики и рекурсии не требуется.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27682/discussion-on-answer-by-qwertiy----2100-).